# What is pixel format of HBITMAP when i get bitmap info with GetBitmapBits?

Tags: winapi, bitmap, gdi, hbitmap

I have HBITMAP hBitmap. I use GetBitmapBits(hbitmap, width * height, buffer);

what is the pixel format written in buffer?

Thanks.

Comment: you can specify this with the superior getdibits, eg as RGBQUADs

Answer (score 3):

You want to use GetDIBits instead.

Check out what MSDN says about it:
[GetDIBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Always ask MSDN (if using Visual Studio)

Answer (score 3):

Can be different, it depends on the bitmap. Here’s a code to find out:

```
BITMAP bmp;
if( 0 == GetObject( hbitmap, sizeof( BITMAP ), &bmp ) ) // handle error
```

From that BITMAP structure you can find out pixel format and other important things about memory layout. For example, here’s a formula for the required buffer size: `bmp.bmWidthBytes * bmp.bmHeight`